# Unwanted bold text?

Tags: errors, bold, compilation-error

I get ***bold*** text without using **"\textbf{}"**, how to resolve that?!

P.S. I'm using **"overleaf"**

```
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash end\{titlepage\}"}:\\
C'est pour << fin de la page de garde: "titlepage" >>

\section{Bibliographie: "ref.bib"}

ljklmklmkù hkhmkljml
```

[image]

The **unwanted bold text** is located in the bottom of the **"guide.tex"** file which is not the main file in my project so I'm including it in the **"main.tex"**

[image]

Here is the summarized code of **"guide.tex"** to see more code above the error:

```
\part{Guide explicatif}

\setcounter{section}{0} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Document principal: "main.tex"}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Dans la préambule du fichier principale, on ajoute les packages nécessaires pour compiler le document avec ses différentes commandes utilisées comme suit: \textit{\textbf{"\textbackslash usepackage[arguments]\{nom du package\}"}} \\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash documentclass[a4paper]\{article\}"}:\\
C'est pour << spécifier le type du document "article" avec taille de page "A4": "a4paper" >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash usepackage[utf8]\{inputenc\}"}:\\
C'est pour << encoder les caractères accentués dans le fichier source >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash usepackage[T1]\{fontenc\}"}:\\
C'est pour << que les caractères accentués soient correctement pris en charge >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash usepackage\{url\}"}:\\
C'est pour << permette de créer un lien hypertexte vers une adresse internet par "\textbackslash url" >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash usepackage\{hyperref\}"}:\\
C'est pour << pour utiliser des hyperliens internes (ou hypertextes) clickables  >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]\{biblatex\}"}:\\
C'est pour << pour ajouter la bibliographie avec "biblatex" >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash input\{pg\_garde.tex\}"}:\\
C'est pour << inclure le contenu du fichier de "la page de garde": "pg\_garde.tex" >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash \textbackslash"}:\\
C'est pour << sauter la ligne: "\textbackslash \textbackslash" >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash \%"}:\\
C'est pour << précéder le symbole "\%" avec "\textbackslash" pour l'ignorer et ne considère pas ce qui suive comme commentaire (sachant que le symbole "\%" est pour ajouter des commentaires qui vont pas être s'afficher avec le texte du document) >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash renewcommand\textbackslash labelitemi\{\textbackslash textbullet\}"}:\\
C'est pour << définir le symbole "•" de la liste à puces qui va suivre (sachant que par défaut c'est "-"): "\textbackslash textbullet" (•) >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash newcolumntype\{S\}\{>\{\textbackslash columncolor\{gray!50\}\} p\{3cm\}\}"}:\\
C'est pour << définir un nouveau style "S" pour une colonne du tableau: la taille "p{3cm}" et la couleur "gray!50" (50\% -concentration- de la couleur "grise") >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash arrayrulecolor\{white\}"}:\\
C'est pour << définir la couleur "white" (blanche) pour les bordures du tableau >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash begin\{tabularx\}\{1.1\textbackslash textwidth\}\{|S|p\{1cm\}...p\{1.3cm\}|\}"}:\\
C'est pour << déclaration d'un tableau avec l'environnement "tabularx" qui va prendre "1.1\%" de la largeur du texte (tableau plus large que le texte pour une meilleure visibilité): "1.1\textbackslash textwidth", en spécifiant le style de la 1ère colonne "S" et la taille de chacunes qui suivent: "|S|p\{1cm\}...p\{1.3cm\}", en utilisant ce symbole "|" pour séparer deux colonnes >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\{\}\&\textbackslash textbf\{Argent\}\&...\&\textbackslash textbf\{Tantale\}\&\textbackslash textbf\{Terres rares\}\textbackslash \textbackslash"}:\\
C'est pour << mettre le contenu de chaque cellule de la ligne entre "accolades": \{..\}, en séparant chaque deux cellules par le symbole: "\&", et mettre le texte en gras avec: "\textbackslash textbf" >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash end\{tabularx\}"}:\\
C'est pour << fin du la structure du tableau >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash caption\{Exemples...associés (DREZET...2016) \textbackslash cite\{lien1\}\}"}:\\
C'est pour << donner une légende au tableau: "\textbackslash caption\{..\}" avec une référence: "\textbackslash cite\{..\}" >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash includegraphics[width=1\textbackslash textwidth,height=10.61cm,keepaspectratio]\{./img/eco.PNG\}"}:\\
C'est pour << définir le fichier source de la figure "./img/eco.PNG",ainsi que les dimensions de son affichage: "width=1\textbackslash textwidth,height=10.61cm,keepaspectratio" >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash url \{https://www.cairn.info/...page-72.htm\}"}:\\
C'est pour << insérer un lien "URL" clickable vers un site web: "\textbackslash url \{..\}" >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash end\{document\}"}:\\
C'est pour << fin du document >>

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Page de garde: "pg\_garde.tex"}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\textbf{"\textbackslash begin\{titlepage\}"}:\\
C'est pour << début de la page de garde: "titlepage" >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash vspace*\{1cm\}"}:\\
C'est pour << laisser un espace verticale: "vspace" de "1cm" >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash textbf\{Écologie numérique\}"}:\\
C'est pour << texte en gras: "textbf" >>\\
\\
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash includegraphics[width=0.4\textbackslash textwidth]\{./img/Orléans_logo.PNG\}"}:\\
C'est pour << insérer une figure >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash Large"}:\\
C'est pour << augmenter la taille de police à: "Large" (14pt) >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash end\{titlepage\}"}:\\
C'est pour << fin de la page de garde: "titlepage" >>

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Bibliographie: "ref.bib"}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Unwanted bold text !!
```

And here is a summarized code of my **"main.tex"** including the preamble to see my packages installation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption} 

\def\frenchtablename{Tableau}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\input{pg_garde.tex} 

\part{Le document: Écologie numérique}

\section{Une société basée sur les échanges d’informations a une empreinte écologique négligeable}

Dématérialisation, virtualisation, cloud, ... leur ensemble, sont de l’ordre de 10\% de la consommation totale, ... l’ensemble de l’aviation civile.\\

...

\renewcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}

\begin{itemize}

    \item L’empreinte écologique de ces produits ... d’une quinzaine d’année seulement (voir le Tableau 1 de la page suivante).\\
    Dans ce tableau, une réserve représente ... un enjeu majeur pour ces technologies.
    
    \item Dans un scénario d’utilisation ... de réduction globale de la consommation électrique.\\

\end{itemize}

\begin{table}[h]

\centering

\newcolumntype{S}{>{\columncolor{gray!50}} p{3cm}}

\arrayrulecolor{white}

\begin{tabularx}{1.1\textwidth}{|S|p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1.7cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.3cm}|}
\hline 
\rowcolor{gray!50} 
{}&\textbf{Argent}&\textbf{Cuivre}&\textbf{Indium}&\textbf{Galium}&\textbf{Germanium}&\textbf{Lithium}&\textbf{Tantale}&\textbf{Terres rares}\\
\hline
\textbf{Usage} & \rowcolor{gray!10} {Contacts & Câbles & Écrans & Leds & Wifi & Batteries & LCD, condensateurs & LCD, aimants}\\
\hline
\textbf{Part de la production mondiale dédiée aux TICs} & \rowcolor{gray!10} {21\% & 42\% & >50\% & 40\% & 15\% & 20\% & 66\% & 20\%}\\
\hline
\textbf{Réserve (ans)} & \rowcolor{gray!10} {15-30 & 40 & 10-15 & 10-15 & 10-15 & grandes & 150 & grandes}\\
\hline
\textbf{Recyclage} & \rowcolor{gray!10} {>50\% & >50\% & >1\% & >1\% & >1\% & >1\% &  >1\% & >1\%}
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Exemples de métaux utilisés dans les TICs et les enjeux associés (DREZET, 2012 ; VIDAL, 2016) \cite{lien1}}

\end{table}

Ces constats motivent trois conclusions préliminaires :
\begin{itemize}
    \item Plus que ... la forêt ;
    
    \item Il est urgent de prolonger... de fabrication et de recyclage ;
    
    \item Les effets induits ... les bénéfices attendus des progrès réalisés.
\end{itemize}

\section{Le télétravail permet de réduire l’empreinte carbone}

Éviter les déplacements ... en partie les bénéfices escomptés :

\begin{itemize}
    \item Travailler à domicile ... les impacts liés à l’habitation ;
    \item Il n’est ni envisagé ... passent 100\% de leur ... en consommation énergétique ;
    \item Le télétravail conduit ... dans l’entreprise ;
    \item Les déplacements secondaires ... des émissions de GES.
\end{itemize}

Au final, en tenant compte de l’ensemble des conditions ... est de 0,1 à 0,5\%. Autrement dit, compte tenu des incertitudes .... collectifs de travail).

\section{Aujourd’hui, on recycle ... électroniques à hauteur de 80\%}

C’est un chiffre trompeur ... d’après l’Ademe, 80\% des DEEE français sont en effet indiqués comme ayant été recyclés dans les filières réglementées. \cite{lien2}\\

Mais regardons plus en détail ce que ce chiffre de 80\% recouvre. Ce taux est calculé .... aujourd’hui à environ 45\% des déchets générés. Quant aux opérations ... dans le processus (de l’ordre de 5\% en poids pour l’aluminium... dans un pays comme la France).\\

Deux conclusions s’ajoutent aux précédentes :
\begin{itemize}
    \item Il est nécessaire, en tant ... pour les petits équipements ;
    
    \item Ce n’est pas parce .... ce type de produits.
\end{itemize}

\section{Les technologies de l’information et de la communication (TICs) permettront en 2030 d’économiser au moins l’équivalent de 10 fois leur propre impact}

De nombreux travaux prospectifs ... aux horizons 2020 ou 2030 (par rapport à la situation actuelle) :

\begin{itemize}
    \item les empreintes liées ... que les data centers et le réseau ;
    
    \item les empreintes liées ... voire l’industrie et l’agriculture.
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[H]

\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=10.61cm,keepaspectratio]{./img/eco.PNG}

\caption{© Natalya Yakouleva, macrovector - Fotolia / Revellin-Falcoz L. ‒ CNRS}

\end{figure}  

Cycle de vie d’un produit : de l’extraction des métaux ... du recyclage de produits divers.\\

Cycle de vie d’un produit : de l’extraction des métaux ... du recyclage de produits divers.\\

Mais un examen plus attentif ... que ceux-ci sont mal évalués.\\

Citons quelques limites critiques ... non renouvelables, sont ignorés.\\

Par ailleurs, certaines phases du cycle ... le rapport 2017 des Chiffres clés du climat \cite{lien3}, l’évolution de l’empreinte carbone ... de produits manufacturés) : 35\% importés en 1995 contre 55\% en 2015, ce qui tend ... plutôt qu’une réduction.\\

En conclusion, au travers de ces exemples... en fonction de nos désirs et de nos pulsions.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=17.36cm,keepaspectratio]{./img/eco2.png}
\caption{Photo © Michel Viala/PhotoPQR- La Depeche Du Midi/MAXPPP»}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}  

Envie 2, société située à Portet-sur-Garonne ... éloignées du monde de l’emploi.\\

« Dès lors que les fractions d’objets ... en très faibles quantités dans les équipements.\\

\textbf{Source:}\\
Numérique et écologie\\
Françoise Berthoud\\
Dans Annales des Mines - Responsabilité et environnement 2017/3 (N° 87), pages 72 à 75\\

\url {https://www.cairn.info/revue-responsabilite-et-environnement-2017-3-page-72.htm}

\printbibliography

\newpage

\input{guide.tex} 

\end{document}
```

P.S. I have summarized the code to make it easier to you to check it, so I deleted unecessary raw text and replaced it by **" ... "**

Comment: Hi can You please show more code, I mean from Your documentclass?

Comment: overleaf is not involved here it is just the tex installation you are using, you would get the same output with any tex stystem. But you need to post an example that produces the problem. The example should be a complete small document

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh I have edited my post adding more code and explanation, please review it. thanks

Comment: @David I have edited my post adding more code and explanation, please review it. thanks

Comment: I tried to run that but firstly I had to commet out `%\input{pg_garde.tex} ` then I got the error `! Misplaced \noalign \end{tabularx}` and so no usable PDF generated.  Please remove all parts not related to the problem so that we can run the example and see the issue,

Comment: note that `\rowcolor{gray!10}` has to be at the start of the row you have it after `&` which can not work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle indeed I do have some errors such as "! Misplaced \noalign.." I just didn't fixed them yet..the "\rowcolor{gray!10}" is indeed at the start of the row and it's functioning.

Comment: Problem solved thanks for your help, it was an underscore causing the issue "Orléans_logo.PNG" => "Orléans\_logo.PNG". Thanks to @Mensch for paying attention and thanks to you Mr. David as well.

Comment: After _any_ error TeX makes essentially no effort to make a usable PDF. If you scroll past an error it simply tries to recover enough to syntax-check the document. After getting the misplaced noalign error it's not worth even looking at the PDf file.

Comment: the rowcolor is _not_  at the start of the row and that is why you are getting the error: it is after `&` so starting in column 2 not column 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never ignore errors in the log file, they can causing problems like you have!

Please see the code:

```
...
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash includegraphics[width=0.4\textbackslash textwidth]\{./img/Orléans_logo.PNG\}"}:\\
C'est pour << insérer une figure >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash Large"}:\\
C'est pour << augmenter la taille de police à: "Large" (14pt) >>\\
\\
\textbf{"\textbackslash end\{titlepage\}"}:\\
C'est pour << fin de la page de garde: "titlepage" >>

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Bibliographie: "ref.bib"}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Unwanted bold text !!
```

There you have `Orléans_logo.PNG`. The undercore is the culprit, mask it with `Orléans\_logo.PNG`.

Then you will get the resulting pdf page:

[image: resulting pdf page]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't pay attention to this one..thanks